# Export product quantity from Magento 2.3 to CSV file

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, csv, quantity, qty

What is the proper code to export qty attribute from Magento 2.3 to CSV.

`$product->getQty();` - doesn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Admin Dashboard

Go: System > Export > Select Entity Type > Export File Format

Comment: programmatically preferably.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 $_productStock = $this->_stockItemRepository->get('product id'); 
 $_productStockQty =  $_productStock->getQty();
```